# Ruby on Rails - Inheritance - Callbacks called multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 classes :

```
ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
User < ApplicationRecord
Instructor < User
```

In ApplicationRecord class, I've implemented 2 callbacks :

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  before_validation :upload_image #Uploads BASE64 image data to AWS
  after_validation :destroy_image #If validations fail, destroy image from AWS
end
```

When I create an Instructor, the `before_validation :upload_image` is called 3 times (I guess because of 2 levels of inheritance). Is there a way to prevent this? I don't want to write this call back in Instructor class as the code in ApplicationRecord is being used by multiple classes.

Also, I noticed that this behaviour doesn't happen the first after I restart rails server. But after performing a second API call, it happens again.

Comment: I figured where the problem is coming from. I am using `devise_token_auth` gem which updates user after each API call. This is why these callbacks are run multiple times.

Comment: Please post your solution as the answer.